# How to use GoogleMap.addMarker in onSensorChanged?

Tags: java, android

How can I rotate my marker when my `onSensorChanged` method is called? I tried this code but I got a NullPointerException. I declared `mMap` as global variable and loaded it in onMapReady. I wanted to use it in my `onSensorChanged` method. How can i solve that?

I got this error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker
>   com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.addMarker(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions)'
>   on a null object reference

```java
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

        latLng_dest = getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("latLng_dest");
        Log.d("LatLng_dest : ", latLng_dest.toString());

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, LOCATION_REQUEST);
            return;
        }
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
        // Call our direction function
        getDeviceLocation();

    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if (event.sensor == mRotationSensor) {
            if (event.values.length > 4) {
                float[] truncatedRotationVector = new float[4];
                System.arraycopy(event.values, 0, truncatedRotationVector, 0, 4);
                updateSensor(truncatedRotationVector);
            } else {
                updateSensor(event.values);
            }
        }

    }

    private void updateSensor(float[] vectors) {
        float[] rotationMatrix = new float[9];
        SensorManager.getRotationMatrixFromVector(rotationMatrix, vectors);
        int worldAxisX = SensorManager.AXIS_X;
        int worldAxisZ = SensorManager.AXIS_Z;
        float[] adjustedRotationMatrix = new float[9];
        SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(rotationMatrix, worldAxisX, worldAxisZ, adjustedRotationMatrix);
        float[] orientation = new float[3];
        SensorManager.getOrientation(adjustedRotationMatrix, orientation);
        azimuth = orientation[0]* FROM_RADS_TO_DEGS;
        float pitch = orientation[1] * FROM_RADS_TO_DEGS;
        float roll = orientation[2] * FROM_RADS_TO_DEGS;
        Log.d("", "updateSensor: Pitch "+pitch);
        Log.d("", "updateSensor: Roll "+roll);
        Log.d("", " "+mMap);
        markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().icon(bitmapDescriptorFromVector(MapsActivity.this, R.drawable.ic_navigation_black_24dp));
        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.svtv2)).setText("Azimuth: "+azimuth+"\n"+"Pitch: "+pitch+"\n"+"Roll: "+roll);

        mMap.addMarker(markerOptions.rotation(azimuth));

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        mFusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        initMap();
        //markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().icon(bitmapDescriptorFromVector(MapsActivity.this, R.drawable.ic_navigation_black_24dp));
        Button button = findViewById(R.id.but_dir);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                textView = findViewById(R.id.svtv);
                textView.setText(instruction);
            }
        });


        /*new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
            }
        },0,1);*/

        //Aquire a reference to the system Location Manager
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) !=
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) !=
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            return;

        }


        final TextView live_inst = findViewById(R.id.svtv2);

        // Define a listener that responds to location updates
        LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.
                //makeUseOfNewLocation(location);
                updateDeviceLocation(location);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            }
        };
        // Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1, 0, locationListener);

        try {
            mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(MapsActivity.SENSOR_SERVICE);
            mRotationSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR);
            mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mRotationSensor, SENSOR_DELAY);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Hardware compatibility issue", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, onSenorChanged would trigger as soon as you launch the app screen.

With this way, after sensor value got changed, you are trying to rotate the marker on the map object, which would be null, as its an async call.

Put a null check just before you call 'rotateMarker' method.

Example:

```
If (mMap != null) {
  // do rotate Map marker
}
```

Note: Sensor values would change even for very minute changes. Just for performance enhancement, calibrate your sensor values with + or - 5.

Hope this info helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried this but it is like mmap isnot null. Because i had this error again. Code entered in the condition and generated error.

Comment: I tried to use boolean as condition to avoid mMap.addMarker before loading OnMapReady. But now the error is addMarker and i have this error :  com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.common.apiexception.b: latlng cannot be null - a position is required.

Answer (score 0):

I solve it.
The solution was to avoid calling mMap.addMarker before OnMapReady. I used first this to avoid null on mMap and also addMarker error that was null on marker's position.

```
if (save) {
        temp_marker.remove();
        temp_marker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions.rotation(azimuth));
    }
```

In my updateSensor and added this in my getDeviceLocation after adding first position in marker :

```
save = true;
```

with save defined as global and initialized to false.

```
if (mMap != null)
```

didn't work. It is why i was confused. I didn't notice that it was double nullPointerException in the same syntax.